# Character is not changing animation state with script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have set up the animator for a character in a 3D game. I then set some conditions to change the animation. In this case, I want the character to change from attack=0 (running) to attack=3 (attacking). It works sometimes, oddly, but most of the times the character is stuck in running animation.
There are some extras on the code, for example, reducing the speed to 0 and checking for a certain script. But I'd like to focus the help on the animation changing part.

I tried enlarging the condition to change the animation but it is not working so far.

```
if (anim.GetInteger("attack") == 0)
        {
            if (transform.position.x > 2f && transform.position.x < 3.5f && transform.position.z == 0 ||
            transform.position.z > -3.5f && transform.position.z < -2f && transform.position.x == 0 ||
            transform.position.x > -3.5f && transform.position.x < -2f && transform.position.z == 0 ||
            transform.position.z > 2f && transform.position.z < 3.5f && transform.position.x == 0)
            {
                if (gameObject.GetComponent<LeftNPCmove>() != null)
                {
                    var go = this.gameObject;
                    var com = go.GetComponent<LeftNPCmove>();
                    com.speed -= com.speed;
                    anim.SetInteger("attack", 3);

                }
```

With the first conditions clause I intend to make the character change animation between the interval specified.
In the second conditions clause I tell it to change the condition in the animator from 0 to 3, thus attacking.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like your positions are not precisely `0`.

Try swapping out your

```c#
transform.position.z == 0
```

for

```c#
Mathf.Abs(transform.position.z) < 0.01f
```

and same for X.

Comment: Thank you. Will try that and comeback later with feedback. I can't do it at the moment.

Comment: Although it made total sense what you said, it still is not working. The characters are still stuck in running animation. I must be screwing it somewhere else.

Comment: I figured it out: I had another condition clause conflicting with it. I'm such a noob. Thank you for your answer, it really helped me look more cautiously to the code!

Answer (score 1):

```#c
transform.position.z == 0
```

etc. are `float` values → **never** compare `float` values directly for equality! The issue you get here is [floating-point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Due to the limited precision there can always be rounding errors making two `float` values that mathematically actually should be equal still different by a tiny value called `epsilon` (also see [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) and [`Mathf.Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html)).

> Floating point imprecision makes comparing floats using the equals operator inaccurate. For example, `1.0 == 10.0 / 10.0` might not return `true` every time.

You should rather use [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) to compare supposed to be exact values

```#c
Mathf.Approximately(transform.position.z, 0)
```

which basically equals

```#c
Mathf.Abs(transform.position.z) < Mathf.Epsilon
```

However, for comparing positions: For moving objects in 3D space it is usually pretty much **never** the case that they have exact positions in one certain frame. Therefore you might rather want to use a broader range like

```#c
Mathf.Abs(transform.position.z) < 0.1f
```

---

Btw you can then shrink your code a little:

```#c
// avoid repeated API calls and calculations
var position = transform.position;
var posXAbs = Mathf.Abs(position.x);
var posZAbs = Mathf.Abs(position.z);

if (posZAbs < 0.1f && posXAbs > 2f && posXAbs < 3.5f
    || posXAbs < 0.1f && posZAbs > 2f && posZAbs < 3.5f)
{
    // avoid repeated and redundant GetComponent call
    var com = GetComponent<LeftNPCmove>();
    if (com)
    {
        // here also could appear floating point imprecision
        // so rather set a fixed value 0
        com.speed = 0; // or e.g. Vector2.zero depending what `speed` is
        anim.SetInteger("attack", 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem still stands, but I got to learn a little more from your comment. I must be doing something wrong somewhere else because the character is still stuck in the running animation when it reaches the coordinates I specify. It's my first game ever, so it's obviously my fault. But I can't seem to find where I have it wrong. Thank you again for the tip on shrinking the code. I chose to leave it as it is for now so I don't mess more things up though. But I changed the values to Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x)<0.1f and it is still not working for me.

Comment: I figured it out: I had another condition clause conflicting with it. I'm such a noob. Thank you for your answer, it really helped me look more cautiously to the code! I've set the correct answer for the guy who answered first about the float values because he has lower reputation and because he answered first. I've tried to upvote your answer but my reputation is not enough to display upvotes. Thank you a lot, really. I hope you understand my reasons. Have a great day.

Comment: That's okey with me ;) Glad you figured it out! In general: Select the answer that solves your specific problem in the best way. If other answers are added later and others find it better it will get upvoted anyway